# Integrating the function $\frac{1}{x}\tan x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to know how to integrate the function:
$\frac{1}{x}(\tan x)$
with respect to $x$.

Comment: No closed form exists.

Comment: Even simpler expressions, such as $~\dfrac{\sin x}x~$ and $~\dfrac{\cos x}x,~$ don't possess elementary antiderivatives $($ see [trigonometric integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) $),$ so why would $~\dfrac{\tan}x~$ be any different ?

Answer (score 1):

As Henry W already commented, no closed form seems to exist even using special functions.

The only possible solution (beside numerical integration) would consist in using $$\tan(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{B_{2n} (-4)^n (1-4^n)}{(2n)!} x^{2n-1}$$ which would lead to $$\int \frac{\tan(x)}x \,dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{B_{2n} (-4)^n (1-4^n)}{(2n-1)(2n)!} x^{2n-1}$$

For illustration purposes, let us consider the integration between $0$ and $\frac \pi 4$. The following table reproduces the result obtained as a function of terms used in the summation.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{integral} \\
 1 & 0.7853981634 \\
 2 & 0.8392285049 \\
 3 & 0.8471977675 \\
 4 & 0.8486190143 \\
 5 & 0.8488953296 \\
 6 & 0.8489518478 \\
 7 & 0.8489638036 \\
 8 & 0.8489663940 \\
 9 & 0.8489669654 \\
 10 & 0.8489670932 \\
 11 & 0.8489671221 \\
 12 & 0.8489671287 \\
 13 & 0.8489671303 \\
 14 & 0.8489671306 \\
 15 & 0.8489671307
\end{array}
\right)$$